# Kubuntu 22.04 / Lenovo T560, when I hold the volume down key pressed, session ends and I end up on the login screen again

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, lenovo, 22.04

Since installing Kubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo T560, I can login by password, but I get **logged out** again, when pressing and holding the volume down key pressed (which is on position F2).

And I don't know, where to look for the logs.

`sudo dmesg`

doesn't provide anything helpful.
Is there a workaround?

EDIT: I found some crash reports (in /var) with the time stamp of these logout events, but I was unable to reproduce the logout by pressing the vol. down key, some days after.
The problem seems solved, possibly by an update.